# Why instantiated Static Mesh gets scaled in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: instance, mesh, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Building a project in Unreal Engine 4.26 while trying to increase the performance of the videogame I ended up using instances of static meshes where possible. This generated an issue:

**My instantiated meshes are scaled to 0.9995/1** (experimentally proven).
Looking for an answer I found a work-around suggested by Unreal Engine devs themselves: they suggested to rotate the mesh adding a rotation of 360 degrees using higher values of the same rotation as you can read [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/540843/instanced-static-mesh-gets-scaled.html). This didn't work for me and, as you can see, the difference between instantiated and manually placed meshes are evident.

[image: evidence]

Following the way I've instantiated the meshes:

[image: code]

Increasing the rotation on **z-axis** using 450 degrees didn't solve anything even though doing it with the meshes provided by devs [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/540843/instanced-static-mesh-gets-scaled.html) actually works.

I'm sure that rotations are the key to solve the problem since the problem is not systematic, I didn't get the logic behind but by building a square with instantiated meshes I end up having some walls with spaces and some of them with perfect scale. I increased the size of them all so as to not have spaces but I'm afraid that the solution will bring more issues in the future while working with light and production materials. Seems that the bug isn't solved yet in UE4, is there another workaround that I may use without any risk of overlapping meshes?

Comment: I have no idea if this is "programming related" as mentioned in the tag-wiki of [tag:unreal-engine4], but either way it's possible that people over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be able to provide better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug not yet solved, to populate the map with objects where is necessary to have a high accuracy level is suggested to place them manually. If you place them manually, UE4 will make them instances, it's not necessary to have a blueprint to populate rooms programmatically.

---

Increasing the scale how I did in the first place doesn't seem to cause problems but I ended up placing them manually since as solution is more elegant even if it requires more effort.